# Automatically upvote comments for the same deletion recommendation in the LQP queue

Tags: feature-request, comments, low-quality-posts

If I am the first one to review an item in the LQP queue, I can choose to add a comment:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

But it does nothing if that exact comment has already been posted by another user.
Instead of doing nothing (and wasting a click) and to keep the incentive to express the reason of the deletion recommendation,  could it upvote the existing comment?

<sub>I can also click on the upvote arrow and *then* recommend deletion without reason; but it breaks the flow of the review and forces me to read the comments, which should not be necessary to judge the quality of an answer. Or is it?</sub>

Comment: There's a similar request, though for "possible duplicate"-comments on MSE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218295/subsequent-duplicate-close-votes-should-automatically-upvote-the-possible-duplic

Comment: I usually just upvote the comment manually then select 'No comment necessary'. That seems to work pretty well.

Comment: For some reason when I started out I thought this is how it already worked. Then I noticed it wasn't and changed my behavior. Kind of surprised that it doesn't do this already. But I think reading the comments should be encouraged, not discouraged.

Comment: I suppose what really "breaks the flow" is that the existing comments are at the bottom, and the "Recommend Deletion" button is at the top.

Comment: [Same request on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253276).

Answer (score 9):

I would actually like to argue *against* this, for a subtle but important reason:

#### Anything that encourages more hasty clicking of a predefined LQP comment is a bad idea at present on SO.

There are a lot of reviewers that feel that all their deletions must be backed up by an auto-comment, and that if something needs to be deleted but there's no auto-comment that really fits, well, they'll ***make*** one fit. By selecting it anyway, however bizarre it looks. (Putting "if you meant to ask clarification from the author" on a low-quality **self**-answer? I've seen that more than once. Putting multiple clashing auto-comments on there without bothering to clarify the differences? Too many times to count.)

Instead, let's cultivate the idea of posting custom comments when necessary, based on actually *reading* the post and *customizing* the response accordingly. Sometimes, as Tiny Giant suggests, upvoting an existing comment is a better idea. Sometimes there really isn't any more commenting necessary. Sometimes the existing auto-comment is unclear and should have a clarification added. And sometimes the issue with the post is not obvious to a reviewer and can only be seen by reading manual comments there! (As a bonus, if you pay attention to comments you can usually spot audits more easily.)

Don't design tooling to take away friction that's holding back poor behavior.

Comment: Questions and answers can be _low quality_ for very different reasons, so a custom comment is the best approach to deal with it. New users will profit most, if we can actually describe, why their posting was low quality, matching their specific posting. We want high-quality questions and answers? Let's provide high-quality feedback!

Comment: True, if someone feels encouraged to read the existing comments, upvote one or more, then click delete *without a comment*, that's a win, not a loss. We should be looking into ways to make that more encouraged, not less.

Comment: IMO, a banner across the top of the auto-comment modal saying something along the lines of "*Please read any existing comments and up-vote the ones that you agree with to avoid posting redundant comments. If the existing comments need clarification, post a custom comment. If all of the applicable reasons are covered by the existing comments, select 'No comment necessary.'*"

Comment: Also, a single word addition might improve "No comment necessary" to "No additional comment necessary".

Comment: If we want to encourage custom feedback, add a radio button for a custom reason (as with close votes).